# Can not read or write external storage even though permissions granted

Tags: android, android-permissions

Permissions are granted but can not read and write

```
boolean write = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
boolean read = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

Log.e(TAG, "aaaa WRITE=" + write + ", READ=" + read);
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Log.e(TAG, "aaaa DIR=" + dir);
Log.e(TAG, "aaaa canRead=" + dir.canRead() + " canWrite=" + dir.canWrite() + " canExecute=" + dir.canExecute());
```

prints:

```
2021-06-12 12:30:07.256 3196-3196/ aaaa WRITE=true, READ=true
2021-06-12 12:30:07.257 3196-3196/ aaaa DIR=/storage/emulated/0
2021-06-12 12:30:07.260 3196-3196/ aaaa canRead=false canWrite=false canExecute=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `requestLegacyExternalStorage` to manifest file:

```
 <application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been deprecated from API 29 as an improvement to user privacy, so the path returned will not directly be accessible to apps that target API 29 or above.

Here’s a link to the documentation for alternatives https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Context.getExternalFilesDir doc: `This is like getFilesDir() in that these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled` - this is not desired behaviour as my application needs access to large amounts of image and other kind of data that needs  to be put into device's internal storage or later in the future in external storage (extarnal SD card) by the user. Of course I could tell users to create specific directories structure themselves and that way I probably could read that but..

Comment: ... I would rather have those directories be created by the app on first launch and then the users would only need to put those large amounts of data in appropriate directories

Comment: You could still create directories from the app, it will just be cleaned up on uninstallation. What’s your specific usecase though?

Comment: User needs to upload to the device images, zip files and text files which are designed to display maps data (from few hundred MB to few GB). Each user will have individual data sets that he prepares/collects for himself. In the case of accidental uninstall user must not lose that data.

Comment: Well in case you want the data to persist despite app uninstallation the viable options are to use Storage Access Framework or MediaStore APIs (former maybe better suited). For more information please check out the documentation here --> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage